# Why when I use mutate and replace function for some of the columns I get error that ''input XX can't be recycled to size X''?

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I am in the process of learning dplyr and mutate and replace functions. I have already used this function for data cleaning before and it worked. However, for some reason when I try to do it on some other example, it gives me an error.

So I have data frame

```
> color= c("blue", "black", "blue", "blue", "black")
> x = 1:5
> y = 6:10
> z = 11:15
> df <-data.frame(color,x,y,z)
> df
```

So I tried replacing the values of variable x and it worked

```
> df <- df %>% 
+   mutate(x_1 = replace(x,1,10))
> df <- df %>% 
+   mutate(x_2 = replace(x,2,10)) %>% 
+   mutate(x_3 = replace(x_2,1,25))
> df
  color x  y  z x_1 x_2 x_3
1  blue 1  6 11  10   1  25
2 black 2  7 12   2  10  10
3  blue 3  8 13   3   3   3
4  blue 4  9 14   4   4   4
5 black 5 10 15   5   5   5
```

However, when I try replacing the values of some other variables it shows the following error.

```
> df <- df %>% 
+   mutate(y_1 = replace(y,6,11))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `y_1`.
> x Input `y_1` can't be recycled to size 5.
> i Input `y_1` is `replace(y, 6, 11)`.
> i Input `y_1` must be size 5 or 1, not 6.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```
> df <- df %>% 
+   mutate(z_1 = replace(y,11,25))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `z_1`.
> x Input `z_1` can't be recycled to size 5.
> i Input `z_1` is `replace(y, 11, 25)`.
> i Input `z_1` must be size 5 or 1, not 11.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

What could be the reason that it works for one variable but not for others?

Answer (score 1):

The middle argument of replace is an "index vector". The examples you show that "work" you are replacing the value at that position (but not that value itself) with the replacement value. For example, given a vector `a = 10:15`, `replace(a, 2, 1)` returns `10 1 12 13 14 15`. This is also why `replace(a, 10, 1)` doesn't work. The length of the vector is only 5, so you can't replace the 10th element in the vector (it doesn't exist, the vector is not that long). If you want to replace a specific value, your "index vector" needs to be a logical value like so: `replace(a, a == 10, 1)`. HTH.

PS - It's helpful to format your code as code using the formatting options on the website.